# Как составить sql запрос с несколькими джоинами?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Нужно выбрать записи из таблицы `product` где `product.avaibility_poition = 1` у которых:
`product.id` = `priority_category_product.product_id`, `prirority_category_product.category_id = 55` и `priority_category_product.vehicle_group_id` равна группе у которой `vehicle.model_id = 22`, `vehicle.brand_id = 33`

Есть кусок запроса.

```
SELECT product.id FROM product
INNER JOIN priority_category_product
    ON product.id = priority_category_product.product_id
WHERE priority_category_product.category_id = 55
    AND priority_category_product.vehicle_id = ?????...
```

Как дальше быть?

Структура таблиц:

> ```
> create table product
> (
>   id int,
>   category_id int,
>   name text,
>   avalibility_position int
> )
> ```

> ```
> // Таблица связей
> create table priority_category_product
> (
>   id int,
>   category_id int,
>   vehicle_group_id int,
>   product_id int,
>   position int
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table vehicle_group
> (
>   id int,
>   name text
> )
> ```

> ```
> // Таблица связей
> create table vehicle_group_vehicle
> (
>   id int,
>   vehicle_group_id int,
>   vehicle_id int
> )
> ```

> ```
> create table vehicle
> (
>   id int,
>   brand_id int,
>   model_id int
> )
> ```

[fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f1406c757f09387f136c5d533e587b3)

Comment: дак и пишите несколько джойнов подряд, в чем проблема?

Comment: Покажите явно ВСЕ связи, для каждой пары таблиц, уж коли они не сформированы как FK. PS. И что это за fiddle, без sample data и desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так что ли? Пишите несколько джойнов подряд, если вам надо. Сложности вроде никакой нет?

```
SELECT distinct p.*
FROM product as p 
INNER JOIN priority_category_product as pcp ON (
        p.id = pcp.product_id
        and pcp.category_id = 55
    )
INNER JOIN vehicle_group_vehicle as vgv ON (
        pcp.vehicle_group_id = vgv.vehicle_group_id
    )
INNER JOIN vehicle as v ON (
        v.id = vgv.vehile_id
        AND v.brand_id = 33
        AND v.model_id = 22
    )
WHERE 
    p.avaibility_poition = 1
```

таблица `vehicle_group` в запросе не участвует.

Comment: Спасибо! Еще вопрос, возможно ли модифицировать вышеприведенный запрос так, чтобы выбирались все продукты, но сортировались по указанным условиям? Или лучше сделать это отдельным запросом типа `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY (ids)`?

Comment: @Jeque что значит сортировались по этим условиям? Чтобы выбрать все, сделайте `LEFT JOIN`, а отсортировать сможете потом в т.ч. по полю `v.id`, оно будет `null`, если перечисленные условия не выполнены. Ну или проясните, принципы сортировки

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно